# Makefile issue in C LINUX

Tags: c, linux, makefile, dependencies

I have the following files in a folder:

main.c | file1.c | file1.h | file2.c | file2.h

main.c is dependent on file1.h and file2.h.
However, file1.c is also dependent on file2.h, and this is my problem.

Here's what I have:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

BIN = main


all: $(BIN)


main: main.o file1.o file2.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

main.o: main.c file1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

file1.o: file1.c file1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

file2.o: file1.c file1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(BIN)
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

What can I do to make my makefile work? And to improve it?

EDIT:

In main.c:

```
#include "file1.h"
```

In file1.c:

```
#include "file1.h"
```

In file1.h:

```
#include "file2.h"
```

In file2.c:

```
#include "file2.h"
```

I have no includes in file2.h.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: This is why I use `automake` and do not worry about this sort of stuff.

Comment: If “main.c is dependent on file1.h and file2.h,” then the line `main.o: main.c` should be `main.o: main.c file1.h file2.h`. (Note that it is main.o, not main.c, that depends on file1.h and file2.h. Unless the **contents** of main.c must change when file1.h or file2.h changes.) Other than this, why do you say “Obviously this doesn’t work”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add file2.h as a dependency of file1.o

It should work.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `make`'s wildcard matching. For the demonstration, I filled the files with some simple functions.

file2.h

```
void func2(void);
```

file2.c

```
#include "file2.h"

void func2()
{
        return;
}
```

file1.h

```
#include "file2.h"

void func1();
```

file1.c

```
#include "file1.h"

void func1()
{
        func2();
        return;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "file1.h"

int main()
{
        func1();
        return 0;
}
```

Now, you can use `make`'s wildcard matching, Ex, `*.o : *.c` for producing `.o` file from any `.c` file.

Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
OBJS = main.o file1.o file2.o
BIN = main

all : $(BIN)

main: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

*.o : *.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
clean:
        rm -f *.o $(BIN)
```

Terminal Session

```
$ ls 
file1.c  file1.h  file2.c  file2.h  main.c  Makefile
$ make 
gcc -Wall -g   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -g   -c -o file1.o file1.c
gcc -Wall -g   -c -o file2.o file2.c
gcc -Wall -g -o main main.o file1.o file2.o
$ ./main
$ make clean 
rm -f *.o main
$ ls 
file1.c  file1.h  file2.c  file2.h  main.c  Makefile
```

In general, it is advised to keep `.h` files separately, Ex, having `includes` directory. With that modification, `Makefile` becomes

Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -I./includes
OBJS = main.o file1.o file2.o

main: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

*.o : *.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
clean:
        rm -f *.o $(BIN)
```

Terminal Session

```
$ ls 
file1.c  file2.c  includes  main.c  Makefile
$ ls includes/
file1.h  file2.h
$ make 
gcc -Wall -g -I./includes   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -g -I./includes   -c -o file1.o file1.c
gcc -Wall -g -I./includes   -c -o file2.o file2.c
gcc -Wall -g -I./includes -o main main.o file1.o file2.o
$ ./main 
$ make clean 
rm -f *.o main
$ ls
file1.c  file2.c  includes  main.c  Makefile
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Alcachofra Since you are new to the community, please give a refresh to this link, [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)